# What is an antonym of improved/improvement?

Tags: meaning, antonyms

Consider these sentences:

- "I improved my essay."
- "I made an improvement to my essay."
- "How much did you improve your essay?"
- "What improvements did you make to your essay?"

What would I say, if I meant the opposite, like

- "I changed my essay in a negative way."
- "I made a change to my essay that negatively affected it."
- "How much did you change your essay in a negative way?"
- "How many negative changes did you make to your essay?"

Ideally, this would be a word or short phrase that would work well in other sentences too.

---

**EDIT** Additional example:

- "Most improvements were due to me, but this one was made by John."

I'm looking for a verb and a noun. (They don't have to share the same stem, though that'd be great if they did.)

Comment: Did you check [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/improvement)?

Comment: @tchrist, yes. Generally speaking, the quality of that resource for finding antonyms is poor compared to the insight that ESE brings.

Answer (score 3):

I think I like **regress(ed|ion)** or **deteriorat(ed|ion)**.

[Comparing the words to "worsen"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=regression,deterioration,worsen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1;,regression;,c0;.t1;,deterioration;,c0;.t1;,worsen;,c0) [which I believe is barely English].

> Usage:
>
> My essay quality deteriorated as I made each edit.
>
> How did your essay regress after making changes?

_

---

_

> regress: return to a former or less developed state.
>
> deteriorate: become progressively worse.

Answer (score 2):

"I degraded [the {quality / standard} of] my essay".

Comment: So what would call that if you need a noun...a degregation?

Comment: A *degradation*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **worsen**.

I worsened my essay and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The patient did not improve; she worsened.

Comment: And the noun form...a worsening? ("Those worsenings to my essay were made by Jack.")

Comment: Yes..........but its use is not extremely common.

Comment: I hardly hear worsen.

Comment: I came across this word recently in Jules Verne's *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea* (translated by F. P. Walter). Good book, but don't read the abridged versions.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I agree...I rarely hear **any** antonyms for progress

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - you don't hear regression or deterioration?

Answer (score 0):

**Pejorate**: [To make worse; to deteriorate or to worsen.](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/133946/pejorate)  Synonyms for [pejorate](http://thesaurus.com/browse/pejorate)

Answer (score 0):

**[Ruined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ruined)**: Cause great and usually irreparable damage or harm to; have a disastrous effect on. (Also consider: *destroyed*)

Note, this word can also have a positive connotation depending on its use.

> I rewrote my essay and completely ruined it!

---

*I* **[messed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/messed_up)**/**[f*cked](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fucked_up)** *it up*: Same as above, more expressive (informal and/or offensive/impolite).

Note, unlike the former suggestion, these do not (and most likely will not) have a positive connotation, just varying degrees of negativity.

> I rewrote my essay and completely messed/f*cked it up.
>
> I hit a wall with my car and completely messed/f*cked it up.

---

**[Parvum opus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parvum_opus)**

The opposite to Magnum opus (Latin for 'Greatest/best work'). Parvum opus literally means 'small work'. In this context you could say:

> I wrote an excellent essay, my *magnum opus*, but after editing it I've turned it into a *parvum opus* instead.

Addendum: These can all be applied to 3rd person.

> John ruined my essay.
>
> John messed/f*cked my essay up.
>
> John turned my beautiful essay into a *parvum opus*.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[**corrupt**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corrupt)" and "[**corruption**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corruption)."

> [**corrupt**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corrupt): to alter (a language, text, etc.) for the worse; debase.

- "I corrupted my essay."
- "I made a corruption to my essay."
- "How much did you corrupt your essay?"
- "How many corruptions did you make to your essay?"
- "What corruptions did you make to your essay?"
- "Most corruptions were due to me, but this one was made by John.

Comment: Most of your sentences don't make sense in English.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd You bet they don't make sense. Do you know a lot of people that would change their essay to make it worse? Come on, RB! ;-)

Comment: I am talking about grammatically they hardly make sense.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the following for each of your examples:

> I harmed my essay.

or:

> I damaged my essay.

or, better:

> I made my essay worse.

The others are a bit harder, how about:

> Did you make it *much* worse?
>
> How did you harm your essay?

or:

> How did you make your essay worse?

I don't think you'll find a verb that is the direct antonym of *improve*. You will have to change your sentences around and use different words depending on the context and what it is that you have harmed/worsened/destroyed/spoiled/broken etc.

Answer (score -3):

You could say:

- I clogged the improvement of my essay.
- I hampered the progress of my essay.